# Firebase Realtime Database user data access based on uid

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a rule for create/access the FRD data based on authenticated user. But am getting an error where running the **`Rules Playground`**

What I want is, Users are creating the categories. So Users is able to only read their categories and update those categories.

**Rule:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth != null && $uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "auth != null && $uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "categories": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth != null && $uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "auth != null && $uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Auth Users:**

[image: Here is authentication users to firebase]

**Realtime Database**

***Categories***
[image: This is categories table]

***Users***
[image: This is users table]

***Categories Write function in Flutter***

```
String uId = await userId();
      final databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('categories');
      var data = await databaseRef.get();
var index = data.children.length;
      await databaseRef.child('$index').set(<String, dynamic>{
        "name": categoryBody.name,
        "description": categoryBody.description,
        "uid": uId,
        "id": index,
      });
```

***Error***
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there anything wrong with the rules that am applying?

Comment: Can you share error you are facing?

Comment: Added error screenshot @RoopaM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your issue, but I can able to successfully test rules without errors.

The rules you are using are for authenticated users but you are testing for unauthenticated users.  Means you have not enabled `Authenticated` field.

And you have to enter `/categories/uid` instead of `/categories` under the location and you should enter `uid` under `Firebase UID` field. You may have look at below screenshot.

[image]

You can refer this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/dx_gkSb-Ch0?t=992) for more information.

Comment: Hi Roopa M, thanks for your answer. I tried your solution, but getting same simulation error. In my case Provider is **password**. passed the uid to Firebase UID field. 

Attached new screenshots to my question, kindly check. Thanks!

Comment: @rjkolli7 You are passing value of `uid` to `firebase UID`. Try passing just `uid` as shown in my [screenshot](https://i2.paste.pics/JMK65.png)

Comment: Thanks for the input Roopa M, it's working perfect. But when am trying to write categories and read categories from my app it is not working. It's throwing **PERMISSION DENIED** error. I attached the code to my question, kindly check. Thanks!

Comment: @rjkolli7, It could be a problem with plugins. Make sure, you have included the correct versions of plugin. if you are still facing the issue, Can you share the document or tutorial if you are following any?

Comment: I understand the structure for this @Roopa M. Actually my structure of categories is is starting with index. But am looking for the uid inside the child of categories. So for that I changed the structure from 

"categories":[
"index": {},
]

to

"categories":[
"uid": {},
]

Now it is working.

Comment: @rjkolli7 Happy to hear that your issue is resolved. Consider upvoting or accepting my answer if you are satisfied with my solution, so that it also helps others who are facing the same issue to find solution at first glance

Comment: Yes , it's helped me to find other way solution for my problem. But am still looking how to restrict users to access the categories list when the categories list format is like this, "categories":[ "0": {"uid": "1jhpK0QbhNUsDlV1Vznoy0AiyW62", "name": "abc"}]

Could you help me in this?

Comment: @rjkolli7 what I understood from your comment is, how to restrict a user when `categories` changed to above structure? As you applied security rules, it allows only authorized users based on UID's and it doesn't depend on format. I believe it will restrict unauthorized users. If I misunderstood could you please explain your question in detail?

Answer (score 1):

When you're using the following security rules:

```
"categories": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "auth != null && $uid === auth.uid",
    ".read": "auth != null && $uid === auth.uid"
  }
}
```

It means that you allow the user to write/read to/from every child that exists under your `categories/$uid` node. So when you try to apply those rules to your actual database structure, it's the expected behavior to see that Firebase servers reject the operations since it doesn't find any `$uid` level in your database schema. To solve this, you have to remove that extra `$uid` level from rules like this:

```
"categories": {
  ".write": "auth != null",
  ".read": "auth != null"
}
```

And this is because those category objects exist directly under the `categories` node and **not** under `categories/$uid`.

Comment: Hey rjkolli7. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hi Alex Mamo, Thanks for your answer. I tried above solution, but $uid am unable to fetch. It's giving error **Unknown Variable $uid**

Comment: Oh, yes. That's correct. Sorry, my bad. The UID is not the document ID. So please check my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Yes, the above one working Alex Mamo, This is every logged-in user able to read all categories.  But my case is only authorised user's only able to read their data. So am using uid for that.

Comment: In that case, you should add an extra level to your database, which is the UID, and leave the rules exactly as they are, right? Give it a try and tell me if it works.